# How to Open many NEW windows in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup

Wondering how to open many new windows with Javascript.  I have found plenty of places on the internet that show you how to open a new browser window with Javascript, but I want to open a new UNIQUE window.  For Example.

I have two links on a page.  the user clicks on both links and they are both opened in the same window.  I want each link to open a new window WITH JAVASCRIPT.

Another Example.
**I just opened a window with javascript and I have a link inside my newly opened window.  I click on the link and it opens in the same window.  I want to pop it out of that window WITH JAVASCRIPT, NOT use the same window.**

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.open('page.html','WindowTitle','width=400,height=200')
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was the WindowTitle that I needed to change to create new windows....

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous poster said, you want `window.open(...)`

```
var WindowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName [, strWindowFeatures]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open

Make sure that you have different `strWindowName` for each call since that determines which window the URL is opened in.